# Is there a performance penalty for backgrounding a process?

Tags: process, performance, background-process, process-management, benchmark

If I do:

```
sleep 1
```

versus

```
sleep 1 & wait $!
```

will there be any difference in terms of CPU usage for spawning a foreground process versus a background process? Or will the performance of both lines be exactly equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

On my system the first takes 3.0 ms and the second takes 3.3 ms CPU time.

In practice I would never worry about the 0.3 ms CPU time if you are sleeping a full second.

The 0.3 ms is probably caused by the extra `fork` that is needed to put `sleep` in the background. In other words: It is a one-time cost, not a 10% extra cost for running jobs in the background.

Comment: I added that sleep command just as an example for the script, I ment the question more in general. Is your 0.3 ms difference caused purely by the extra wait command, or are there other reasons?

Comment: Can you explain the extra fork. I don't think that is obvious. Can you also describe how you measured the difference?

Answer (score 1):

With both commands, the shell will 1/ create a parallel subprocess which executes sleep, 2/tell the OS… put the shell process on pause until the sleep process ends. Then the performances are equal.